# How to set view variables to multiple different view in one controller [zend]?

Tags: zend-framework, view, controller

I have stuck with implementing a simple scenario.
I have 2 views for a single controller

```
MyController 
  view/scripts/my/index.phtml
                 /index2.phtml
```

I know `$this->view->test = "test"` will set 'test' view variable for `index.phtml`.
but I would like to know how to set a variable for `index2.phtml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `$this->view->test = "test"` in your controller will set view variables that can be used by any templates rendered afterwards with the call:

`$this->render('your action');`

So for example:

```
class MyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->view->test = "test"

        // Renders my/index.phtml
        $this->render();

        // Renders my/index2.phtml
        $this->render('index2');    
    }
}
```

In both templates you have access to the `test` property.

Comment: rendered aftwards with the call was the issue. I did in reversed way.